# How do run an express-generator created application in production mode?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, npm-start, dev-to-production

I'm using the Express application generator, which recommends starting the server in this manner:

```
$ DEBUG=myapp:* npm start
```

This works and my app starts to listen on the specified port.

However, the `DEBUG` makes me wonder: is this running in 'dev' mode? If so, how do I run it in production mode when deployed on the server?

If I only run `npm start`, it gets stuck:

```
$ npm start

> myapp@0.0.0 start /home/aalaap/projects/myapp
> node ./bin/www
```

There is no line saying that the server is listening and the app is not accessible.

If I run `node app.js`, it exits immediately without any output.

I feel that running the app in debug mode may not be what is ideal for production, but I may be wrong about that if I haven't understood this correctly.

*Edit:* On the server, there's a cron entry that restarts the server in intervals in case it crashes. If the above method is the only way to run it, should I modify the cron command to include the `DEBUG` part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the NODE_ENV environment variable:

```
$ NODE_ENV=production npm start
```

The DEBUG variable you mention is only for log output and configures what exactly you would like to see in the logs.

The question why your application hangs can’t be answered without seeing any code and debugging into it. I hardly doubt that it is related to the environment variables.

Comment: This also causes Node to hang. It seems that unless the `DEBUG` variable is set, Node is unable to run the server. There is nothing to see in the code because it's default express-generator scaffolding. I have not added anything anything else.

Comment: Is the requested port available?

Comment: Yes, the port is free, or else there would be an `EADDRINUSE` error or something.

Comment: I figured it out. The server wasn't hanging, it simply wasn't outputting the "Listening..." status text as it only does that in debug mode. That makes your answer correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command :

npm start

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
Run follwing command:

Replace app-name with
your app name.

SET DEBUG=app-name:* & npm start